# Kubernetes KeyCloak and Traefik configuration

Tags: proxy, kubernetes

I configured KeyCloak with helm with default setting `service.type: ClusterIP` from this Hub

https://hub.kubeapps.com/charts/codecentric/keycloak

I also use Traefik 2.2 to expose Keycloak externally

```
kind: Ingress
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
metadata:
  name: isp-ingress
  namespace: isp
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: traefik
    traefik.ingress.kubernetes.io/router.tls: "true"
    traefik.ingress.kubernetes.io/router.tls.certresolver: default
spec:
  rules:
    - host: my-domain-url
      http:
        paths:
          - backend:
              serviceName: keycloak-http
              servicePort: 80
```

This drives me in white screen of death with the following error:

```
Mixed Content: The page at 'https://my-domain-url/auth/admin/master/console/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure script 'http://my-domain-url/auth/js/keycloak.js?version=keulg'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.
```

In KeyCloak [documentation](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_installation/#_setting-up-a-load-balancer-or-proxy) I found:

> ```
> Configuring your proxy to generate the X-Forwarded-For and X-Forwarded-Proto HTTP headers and preserving the original Host HTTP header is beyond the scope of this guide.
> ```

I think I need to configure Traefik to use a middleware as described [here](https://docs.traefik.io/middlewares/headers/).
I try to put this, taken from the documentation:

```
apiVersion: traefik.containo.us/v1alpha1
kind: Middleware
metadata:
  name: keycloack-header
spec:
  headers:
    sslRedirect: true
```

and apply to my cluster in this way:

```
kubectl apply -f namefile.yaml
```

this the response:

```
middleware.traefik.containo.us/keycloack-header configured
```

and now? where I see this middleware in my console of Traefik?

Try to put in annotation Ingress

```
 annotations:
    traefik.ingress.kubernetes.io/router.middlewares: keycloack-header
```

I receive this error:

```
middleware "keycloack-header@kubernetes" does not exist
```

How can achieve this?
Can someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1):

I'm definitely NOT an expert in this area but have you tried to specify the namespace before the middleware name? In one of my Helm yaml:s I have the following which solved the issue for me (I guess `{{ Release.Namespace }}` would be changed to `isp` in your case ):

```
traefik.ingress.kubernetes.io/router.middlewares: isp-keycloak-header@kubernetescrd
```

Please note: @kubernetes**crd**

Hope this helps!

Cheers